# Serverside random does not work with scroll

Tags: elasticsearch

I use  the following script to create server side random order of retrieving documents:

```
curl -POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search' -d '
{
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "params": {},
            "type": "number",
            "order": "desc",
            "script": "Math.random()"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "fields": [
        "field1",
        "field2"
    ]
}'
```

This script works fine using a regular search.

But If I try to scroll through this, using `search_type=scan` the score seems to be always 0.0 for some reason, and I get the original insertion order.

The order I'm following is according to the docs. First, I call:

```
curl -POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty=true&search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=4' -d '
    {
        "sort": {
            "_script": {
                "params": {},
                "type": "number",
                "order": "desc",
                "script": "Math.random()"
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "fields": [
            "field1",
            "field2"
        ]
    }'
```

and then:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?pretty=true&scroll=10m&scroll_id=<the-previously-returned-id-here>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scan` is a special search type that is optimized for getting back very large result lists. As a result of such optimization, the `scan` search type doesn't support any sorting. So, in your case sort parameters are simply ignored. In order to get sorted results back you need to use some other search type that supports sorting. The default search type `query_then_fetch` should work as long as sort values will fit into memory for all records in your result list. A side effect of using `query_then_fetch` is that sorting will be executed on each page and therefore it has to be consistent between calls:

```
curl -POST 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty=true&scroll=10m&size=4' -d '
{
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "params": {},
            "type": "number",
            "order": "desc",
            "script": "(doc[\"_uid\"].value + salt).hashCode()",
            "params": {
                "salt": "some_random_string"
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "fields": [
        "field1",
        "field2"
    ]
}'
```

After first query standard scroll request can be used to page through results.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?pretty=true&scroll=10m&scroll_id=<the-previously-returned-id-here>
```

Comment: Will this determine a random order once and then let me page through this? How do I page then, using "from" and "size"? My database has soms 10m records, so `Math.Random` takes some good 30 seconds to calculate. I have no problem of waiting these 30 second once, but If I have to do this every page...

Comment: If you want them sorted you will have to wait for sort on every page, unfortunately. Otherwise, you can pull everything using scan and sort them on the client side. I fixed the answer.